In iOS 18, using AudioUnit for audio recording, converting PCM format to AAC crashes the application
 AudioBufferList* convertPCMToAAC (XDXRecorder *recoder) {
UInt32   maxPacketSize    = 0;
UInt32   size             = sizeof(maxPacketSize);
OSStatus status;

status = AudioConverterGetProperty(_encodeConvertRef,
                                   kAudioConverterPropertyMaximumOutputPacketSize,
                                   &size,
                                   &maxPacketSize);
//    log4cplus_info("AudioConverter","kAudioConverterPropertyMaximumOutputPacketSize status:%d \n",(int)status);

AudioBufferList *bufferList             = (AudioBufferList *)malloc(sizeof(AudioBufferList));
bufferList->mNumberBuffers              = 1;
bufferList->mBuffers[0].mNumberChannels = _targetDes.mChannelsPerFrame;
bufferList->mBuffers[0].mData           = malloc(maxPacketSize);
bufferList->mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize   = kTVURecoderPCMMaxBuffSize;

AudioStreamPacketDescription outputPacketDescriptions;

UInt32 inNumPackets = 1;

pthread_mutex_lock(&pcmBufferMutex);

status = AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer(_encodeConvertRef,
                                         encodeConverterComplexInputDataProc,
                                         pcm_buffer,
                                         &inNumPackets,
                                         bufferList,
                                         &outputPacketDescriptions);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&pcmBufferMutex);
if(status != noErr){
    //        log4cplus_debug("Audio Recoder","set AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer status:%d inNumPackets:%d \n",(int)status, inNumPackets);
    free(bufferList->mBuffers[0].mData);
    free(bufferList);
    return NULL;
}

if (recoder.needsVoiceDemo) {
    OSStatus status = AudioFileWritePackets(recoder.mRecordFile,
                                            FALSE,
                                            bufferList->mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize,
                                            &outputPacketDescriptions,
                                            recoder.mRecordPacket,
                                            &inNumPackets,
                                            bufferList->mBuffers[0].mData);
    //        log4cplus_info("write file","write file status = %d",(int)status);
    if (status == noErr) {
        recoder.mRecordPacket += inNumPackets; 
    }
}

return bufferList;
}

The above code for converting PCM to AAC works normally in iOS versions below 18, but in iOS 18, crashes occur during the conversion process. The console does not provide much useful information, and the application crashes at malloc(maxPacketSize) or AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer(), displaying the message AURemoteIO::IOThread (14): EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0). Please help identify the cause of the crash.
I hope to completely solve this crash problem.

can you include encodeConverterComplexInputDataProc and the crash dump?

In an effort to enforce tighter memory safety, iOS 18 introduced new memory allocation features:

The system memory allocator (malloc(3)) has switched to a new implementation for most allocation sizes. Users might experience exposure of latent memory access bugs due to changes in heap layout, differences in performance for allocation-heavy workloads, and changes in fragmentation. (127493322)

This likely includes changes in how memory allocation for zero-sized buffers is handled to guard against information disclosure and other memory safety issues.
According to the malloc documentation:

Crashes in memory allocators are almost always related to heap corruption, such as overflowing an allocated chunk...

You are not checking the return status of the AudioConverterGetProperty function.  Check that maxPacketSize is initialized and not zero as a result of this call.  Also check that the size is actually sufficient.
iOS & iPadOS 18 Release Notes
malloc(3) — Linux manual page

MaxPacketSize and the size of the cache before you agree, can from the above, do not use the
status = AudioConverterGetProperty (_encodeConvertRef,
kAudioConverterPropertyMaximumOutputPacketSize,
&size,
&maxPacketSize); 

The computed maxPacketSize
